# Android : Combine normal widget and SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have create a screen with two kind of views : normal view (buttons to receive up/down action ) and surfaceview. The SurfaceView implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and run on another thread and have a method name `Tick()`.

When those buttons receive action, they will call method `Tick()`,  and I want this method will run same thread with SurfaceView (for synchronize purpose), but don't know how to.

Please give me some idea for my issues.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to run `Tick()` method in separate thread which also draws on the surface you can use [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) for it. So you will be able to create [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for it and post runnables which will be executed in this thread. But this also will put some restrictions on your drawing routine - you need to prevent it from sleeping or waiting because thread need to process message queue.

But actually I suppose any other reasonable way of synchronization will be easier than running this method on the same thread.